# In Angular facotry initialized value again initialize or not to the variable?

Tags: angularjs

In Angular , Not Need code but just clear my doubt about that if I initialize value in factory and Application refresh then factory again initialize value or not ?

Comment: didyou get the solution

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh a page all your context is lost , Because everything is stored in memory and it's destroyed.Its better to use [`localstorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for the same purpose.